# TinyMCE editor turns white on Biographical info

Tags: plugin-development, tinymce

I tried out the solution found here: [How to use tinyMCE for user “biographical info” without messing with any core file?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33552/how-to-use-tinymce-for-user-biographical-info-without-messing-with-any-core-fi/33575#33575) and added it to my plugin code.

The problem is, it turns the editor white (see this picture--> https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCx5Q.png)

How do I make it show up?

Regards,

John

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the plugin linked from one of the answers? This answer [specifically](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42113/1687). The plugin recommended os called [Visual Biography Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/visual-biography-editor/). Apparently it works with the latest version of Wordpress and it's a plugin, so it means no editing any files to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code I provided [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43741/show-only-oldest-post-by-author/43742#43742). It was tested in the latest WordPress and works just fine.